# Can I stream the contents of a window to another control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, controls, viewport3d

I have a `Grid` control which contains a `Viewport3D` amongst some other things and I would like to have a "live preview" of this `Grid`'s contents drawn in another control using WPF.  Can anyone tell me the best/fastest way to do this? :)

In an ideal world I'd like to avoid serialising to a bitmap and copying the buffer manually since the `Grid` control has a large resolution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) is what you are looking for. But i'm not sure if this works with 3D Content.

Comment: Good question, I'll have a play.  Shame VisualBrush is a sealed class.

Comment: Yea, it renders the 3D content but unfortunately I can't hit test the contents of the `VisualBrush`.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/2d-3dinteraction.aspx?msg=1690805&display=Mobile) might help, under Viewport Hittesting.

Comment: Btw stick in an answer and I'll mark it as ok - http://tinypic.com/r/30hngx4/5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) is what you are looking for.
And for [Hittesting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/2d-3dinteraction.aspx), this should be helpful.